# How to test checkbox toggle with Cypress and @testing-library/cypress ,

Tags: javascript, cypress, testing-library, cypress-testing-library

I am trying to write to test toggle action of accordion using cypress testing library.
Below is the Markup for accordion, it is being toggled using checkbox hack :

```
 <div class='accordion'>
                <div class='accordion__item'>
                    <input style="display:none" type="checkbox"  id="item1"/>
                    <label class="accordion__itemLabel"for="item1">FAQ's</label>
                    <div style="display:none" class="accordion__itemContent"> FAQ Content Here </div>
                </div>
                <div class='accordion__item'>
                    <input style="display:none" type="checkbox"  id="item2"/>
                    <label class="accordion__itemLabel"for="item2">Contact us details</label>
                    <div style="display:none" class="accordion__itemContent"> Contact us details here </div>
                </div>
 </div>
```

and Tests is below :

```
    it("should toggle accordion ", () => {
            const checkbox = cy.findByRole({ role: "checkbox" });
            expect(checkbox.checked).equal(false);
            cy.get(".accordion__itemContent").invoke("display").equal("none")
            fireEvent.click(checkbox)
            expect(checkbox.checked).equal(true);
            cy.get(".accordion__itemContent").invoke("display").equal("block")
        })
```

The problem is `cy.findByRole({ role: "checkbox" });` always returns undefined , how can I fix this or write above test in a right way .

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [the Cypress Testing Library examples](https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro#examples), instead of passing the role in an object (`cy.findByRole({ role: "checkbox" })`), you should be passing it as the first argument:

```js
cy.findByRole("checkbox");
```

Beyond that, as Jonah pointed out, I think your test may be failing because you are trying to assign the return value of `cy.findByRole` to a variable. In Cypress, everything is asynchronous, so you need to *chain* your assertions. This is explained in more depth in [the Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Chains-of-Commands).

Here is your test case rewritten with all of the above in mind:

```js
cy.findByRole("checkbox").should("not.be.checked");
cy.get(".accordion__itemContent").invoke("display").equal("none")
cy.findByRole("checkbox")
  .check()
  .should("be.checked");
cy.get(".accordion__itemContent").invoke("display").equal("block")
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `cy.findByRole({ role: "checkbox" });` if the checkbox has nice id ( `id="item1"`)? I would simply use `cy.get('#item1')` in order to get the required checkbox.

In addition, if you want to check the checkbox, the Cypress has method for that `.check()` and `.uncheck()` for deselecting.

In summary your code could be:

```
it("should toggle accordion ", () => {
        cy.get('#item1').should('not.be.checked')
        cy.get(".accordion__itemContent").invoke("display").equal("none")
        cy.get('#item1').check().should('be.checked')
        cy.get(".accordion__itemContent").invoke("display").equal("block")
    })
```

Comment: Thanks Jonah for reply , I am not using id selector to make the tests implementation free and rely only on findByRole / text etc.. from cypress-testing-library to ensure that tests don't break when we change the class names or id etc